# How many string types exist in C++?

Tags: c++, string, types

There are surely many ways how to use strings in C++: `char*`, `w_char*`, `CString`, `std::string`, then some typedefs like `LPTSTR` and other permutations of letters that no one except experienced C++ programmers understands.

I remember reading an article (a long time ago), where the author was criticising C++ for its inconsistency when dealing with strings. He gave an exact number of various string types in C++. I would like to either find this article, or some other reference that provides a number of string types available in C++.

Because obviously, one can create yet another typedef any time, the question is:
**What is the highest lower bound of number of generally used string types known today in C++?**

Comment: Unfortunately this question has no answer. Get an exact number and I'll create a new string type, so it'll be `++exactNumber`

Comment: The the question is to get the highest lower bound known today ;)

Comment: The question in the title, "How many string types exist in C++?", _is_ a real question. The question in bold, "What is the highest lower bound of number of generally used string types known today in C++?", is not.

Comment: There are precisely 768 string types known in C++ at this moment.  I have a webpage which counts them automatically by scanning every known C++ programmer's computer and creates a `std::map` of each string type.

Answer (score 1):

> **How many string types exist in C++?**

Three string types are defined in the language (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28C%2B%2B%29)):

- `std::string` (a typedef for `basic_string<char>`)
- `std::wstring` (a typedef for `basic_string<wchar_t>`)
- `basic_string` (a class template)

A `char *` is not a string. It is a pointer to a `char`.

A `w_char*` is not a string. It is a pointer to a `w_char`.

`CString` is not defined in the language.

Of course I could create my own string-like type: `CCoolString`. When you append an 's' to it, it is stored as a 'z'. But it's not part of the language itself - it's just my code. Internally, it would use an `std::string`.

---

> **What is the highest lower bound of number of generally used string types known today in C++?**

Not a real question. It cannot be answered, because it depends on the users.

Comment: That is why I have referred to char* as one of the "ways how to use strings in C++"

Comment: And I am also not asking about types that are part of the language specification, rather about commonly used string types.

Comment: @Marek I tried to clarify the concept. Actually, one drawback of using char *'s to manage strings is that you can't tell them from other, non-string related, pointers to char; in a function signature, for example.

Comment: You forgot std::wstring and basic_string :)

Comment: "std::string defined in the language"? Absolutely not. It is a part of STL.

Comment: @Pavel: std::string is part of the Standard Library of the language, which is part of the language standard. If you want to implement a C++ compiler you _must_ implement std::string.

Comment: Making it standard library of the language doesn't make it part of the language. A language is a language.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default string type in C++. Using char *, and w_char* one can create whatever amount of string he/she wants. std::string, CString and LPTSTR are all part of different libraries, which I am not sure are part of the standard. (They may be or they may be not). 
You can create your own MarekString which can also be a string type.
And in that C++ is really inconsistent, even I remember a suggestion from Joel Spolsky to make it some default data type.

P.S. you forgot char[] and w_char[], which are slightly different than there * counterpart.

Comment: But there is one: std::string.

Comment: I probably forgot many others, I recall something like "160 ways how to deal with string type" in the original article I was referring to